# Consuming a UMD created by Webpack results in duplicate libs in output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, umd

### Library

I'm creating a React.js library and trying to package it as a UMD for distribution. In the library, the `webpack.config.js` file is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    __dirname+'/modules/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'MyLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals: {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true)
  ]
};
```

Running `webpack` correctly creates a UMD version in `./lib/index.js`.

### Consumer

However, when trying to consume this library in another project, Webpack mistakenly parses the `require('react')` statements within `lib/index.js` in MyLib and includes the React library twice.

The `webpack.config.js` file for the consumer is:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    __dirname + '/src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'index.js'
  }
};
```

The entry point for the consumer is very simple (`src/index.js`):

```
React = require('react');
MyLib = require('my-lib');

console.log('React.Component', React.Component);
```

Running `webpack` in the consumer returns:

```
Version: webpack 1.12.11
Time: 1179ms
   Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
index.js  1.35 MB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./src/index.js 199 bytes {0} [built]
 [170] ../my-lib/lib/index.js 165 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
    + 168 hidden modules

ERROR in ../my-lib/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react' in [...]my-lib/lib
 @ ../my-lib/lib/index.js 3:27-43
```

If I install `react` via npm within `node_modules/my-lib` then webpack will run without errors, but React.js will be included twice in the final output. Inspecting the built file shows that when Webpack encounters `require('react')` in `node_modules/my-lib/lib/index.js` it attempts to included a new version from the local `node_modules` directly instead of the already available version included from `src/index.js`.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here, but I'm not able to make any progress.

Comment: Note: I found a workaround by forcing webpack in the consumer to resolve the root `node_modules` directory first (and thus find the instance of react already included). However this doesn't feel correct...    
    `root: [
          __dirname,
          path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ]`

Answer (score 2):

In `node_modules/react/lib/ReactTransitionGroup.js` React is included as a relative dependency:

```
var React = require('./React');
```

I don't know why in this specific file React is included this way instead of everywhere else in the React package.

```
var React = require('react');
```

Anyway, because of this, then React is included twice, as a [node module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders) (`require('react')`) and as a [file module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) (`require('./React.js')`). Webpack will treat them as two different modules and will add them twice.

I have avoided this duplication making this relative module be an external dependency that points to the same React. The same as you did with the React module, but for both. Then it is only bundled once.

### webpack.config.js

```
var reactExternals = {
  root: 'React',
  commonjs2: 'react',
  commonjs: 'react',
  amd: 'react'
};
var reactDOMExternals = {
  root: 'ReactDOM',
  commonjs2: 'react-dom',
  commonjs: 'react-dom',
  amd: 'react-dom'
};

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    __dirname+'/modules/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: 'index.js',
    library: 'MyLibrary',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals: [
    {
      'react': reactExternals,
      './React': reactExternals,
      'react-dom': reactDOMExternals
    }
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true)
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but it didn't make a difference. I also tried doing the same thing using lodash instead of react to see if there was something particular about react and saw the same issue with lodash.

Comment: @BenSargent I have updated the `webpack.config.js` to ignore `react-dom` as externals too. In my config file it is also in externals because I consider it a `peerDependency` like `react`. Maybe it helps.